# Serializing a complex object AND having the values added to the list of parameters

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I use an api that request me to calculate the signature of my request using some hashing algorithm based on the value of all the parameters I'm sending. If the signature is wrong, my request is rejected. Therefore it is important to me to have a list of all the parameters I'm sending.

I have a complex object that I'm trying to send :

```
public class InboundShipmentPlan
            {
                public InboundShipmentPlan()
                {
                    InboundShipmentPlanRequestItems = new List<InboundShipmentPlanRequestItem>();
                }

            public Address ShipFromAddress { get; set; }
            public string ShipToCountryCode { get; set; }
            public string LabelPrepPreference { get; set; }
            public List<InboundShipmentPlanRequestItem> InboundShipmentPlanRequestItems { get; set; }
        }

        public class Address
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
            public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string DistrictOrCounty { get; set; }
            public string CountryCode { get; set; }
            public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        }

        public class InboundShipmentPlanRequestItem
        {
            public string Prop1{ get; set; }
            public string Prop2 { get; set; }
            public string Condition { get; set; }
            public int Quantity { get; set; }
        }
```

Here is what I' doing :

```
    InboundShipmentPlanRequestItem item = new InboundShipmentPlanRequestItem
        {
            Prop1 = "My",
            Prop2 = "Zorro",
            Quantity = 2
        };

        Address shipmentPlanShipFromAddress = new Address
        {
            AddressLine1 = "25 Courtfield Garden",
            City = "London",
            CountryCode = "UK",
            PostalCode = "SW5 OPG",
            Name = "The Naddler"
        };

        InboundShipmentPlan shipmentPlan = new InboundShipmentPlan
        {
            ShipToCountryCode = "US",
             ShipFromAddress = shipmentPlanShipFromAddress
        };

        shipmentPlan.InboundShipmentPlanRequestItems.Add(item);

        var client = new RestClient(endpointAdresss) {Authenticator = new CustomAuthenticator()};
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST) {Resource = "SomeAction/2010-10-01"};
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddParameter("Action", "CreateInboundShipmentPlan");
        //var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(shipmentPlan);
        request.AddBody(shipmentPlan);
        var response = client.Execute(request);
```

I am calculating the signature in the Authenticator. My problem is that request.AddBody doesn't add my JSON object properties to the list of parameters (request.Parameters), therefore my signature is wrong. The method request.AddObject do add them to the request parameters list, but the problem with this method is that the object is not serialized, therefore the complex properties (Address, etc...) have a value like : System.Collection.Generic.List.

How can I solve this issue ? Thanks

**Update**

I have found that when I use AddJsonObject, it actually adds a parameter whose name is "application/json", and value is the JSON string. However, what I need is that if I have a complex type containing 2 string properties and one property which is a list of a complex type of length n, 2 + n individual parameters be added to the request, and not just one JSON string.

One work around would be to parse the JSON string and convert it to a key value dictionnary, but I haven't found a generic implementation and am not sure if it is worth to dig into it. All the solutions I've found so far were based on the fact that the author knew in advance the structure of the JSON object that he was trying to flatten.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid *Generics* for serialization and use *Arrays* instead.

Also you can use *DataContractSerializer*.

```
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(shipmentPlan.GetType());
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        ser.WriteObject(stream, shipmentPlan);
        var result = Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());
```

After execution result will be correct JSON string:

```
{"InboundShipmentPlanRequestItems":[{"ASIN":"Zorro","Condition":null,"Quantity":2,"SellerSKU":"My"}],"LabelPrepPreference":null,"ShipFromAddress":{"AddressLine1":"25 Courtfield Garden","AddressLine2":null,"City":"London","CountryCode":"UK","DistrictOrCounty":null,"Name":"The Naddler","PostalCode":"SW5 OPG"},"ShipToCountryCode":"US"}
```

With that you can pass object to the server side without any problems.

If you really need all parameters of object for some hashing-algorithm then you should create method inside your object that will generate that hash sequence that you could add as parameters.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't answer my question, I have no problem to serialize the object. My problem is that I need that the properties of all nested objects be added to the list of parameters individually

Comment: So I really misunderstood your question. You send post request with parameters. If you add serialized string as parameter then you can check it on the other side, what am I missed?

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question Vladimir. My problem is that I need to fetch the list of parameters on my side (the client side) before sending the request (this is to create a signature which need to be based on the list of all the parameters I am sending. However, if I add a complex object to my request, consting for eample of 2 string properties, and one property which is a list  of another complex type of length n, it would only add one parameter containing the JSON string, instead of 2 + n parameters.